# What do we do if we need to place a large minion and all minion entry spaces are occupied?

Tags: mice-and-mystics

In Mice and Mystics, we entered a tile and had an encounter which dropped several rats and a spider (which is large).  On the very first turn, the minions ended up defending against an attack and rolling another cheese, triggering a surge, which was a centipede (which is also large).

Large minions are supposed to be the only things that fit on their spaces, but unfortunately every minion entry space was already occupied (either by our mice, rats, or the spider).

What should we do with this newly spawned centipede when he can't fit anywhere?

*(What we ended up doing was having him eat a rat and take the rat's spot, but we were looking for something a little more official.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree, it isn't completely clear from the [rule book](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/images/games/mice-and-mystics/mmrulebook.pdf) what to do. Page 14 covers, **Placing Minions on the Board**, and notes to add new Minions to (not full) minion entry spaces. Luckily, the designer, [Jerry Hawthorne](http://boardgamegeek.com/user/nobeerblues), responded to [that question](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/10427173#10427173) on BGG:

> *Q: We had a situation where a surge called for a centipede, but every spawn space was taken by either a small monster or a mouse. We just didn't spawn the centipede because it couldn't "fit" in any space; was that correct?*
>
> **A: That is correct.**